# How do I make an event listener infinite?

Tags: javascript

Hi im trying to make a geometry dash like game with js and i'm really really stuck on making the player jump.

I can make him jump but only once.

Heres the javascript:

```
   document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) { 
    const key = event.key; 
    switch (key) { 
case "ArrowUp":
    document.getElementById('player').style.animation = "playerJump 0.75s"
    }})
```

It works but only once i want to know how to make the event listener "listen" for ever or until a sertain condition is met.

Comment: it does listen forever - but setting the animation to the same thing as it was (i.e. the second and subsequent times) won't re-run the animation

Comment: Reset the animation property, probably